# MVC3 client side validation fails in area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have many area  in my MVC3 projetc

In my general   web.config
I have

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

But validation is not working at client side
What can I do ?

:(

Comment: where is your from located ? normal view, partial view ? how do you load it? where did you but the script references advised below ? Have you tried to debug with Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools / IE developer tools ?

Answer (score 0):

> But validation is not working at client side What can I do ?

Make sure you have included the following scripts to your pages:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @user444569, are you using TextBoxFor, EditorFor, ... helpers to generate your input fields **inside** a Html.BeginForm?

Comment: And is it inside a form? Are there HTML5 data-* attributes on the generated input field?

Comment: it is inside a form.data-* are rendered in webpage. ModelState.IsValid gives correct value at serverside

Comment: @user444569, have you verified that there are no javascript errors in the console and that all scripts are successfully included (their paths are correct)? I am starting to get short on ideas as this should work. Maybe you can post your code that would allow us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5910/discussion-between-user444569-and-darin-dimitrov)